# batch as 15 minutes in YAML for Build pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-extensions, schema.yml

I am creating a Build pipeline in Azure Devops (earlier VSTS), and want build to get triggered  in BATCH every 15 minutes. If no merge received in repo then no build should be created.

Below is what I am referring to

```
trigger:
    batch: boolean # batch changes if true, start a new build for every push if false
branches:
    include: [ string ] # branch names which will trigger a build
    exclude: [ string ] # branch names which will not
paths:
    include: [ string ] # file paths which must match to trigger a build
    exclude: [ string ] # file paths which will not trigger a build code here
```

This code snippet I took from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema

```
trigger:
    batch: true
branches:
    include:
    - master

pool:
  vmImage: 'Ubuntu-16.04'

variables:
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- script: dotnet build --configuration $(buildConfiguration)
  displayName: 'dotnet build $(buildConfiguration)'
```

1. Only if I receive a  merge in current repo NOW then all rest merges in current repo in another next 15 min would be part of same build. How to add 15 min detail in my YAML document?
2. After current build is Complete and until next merge is received in repo, 15 minutes time should not START? How do I code this in my YAML document?

Comment: I don't think this exact combination can be done.

Comment: related to point 1- You are saying its currently not available in yml? I can do so from VSTS UI though.

Comment: Not in the ui either as far as I can tell

Comment: If possible from the Ui, just setup a build. In the ui and then click the view as yaml button.